# Change the input format in drupal 8

Tags: migrations

I would like to know how to change the input format (automatically or by sql ) for all articles in my website, because I migrated from D6 to D8 and I face a nasty [bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2630578) that requires to edit all my nodes (more than 2000) manually and set either filtered HTML or FULL HTML format to all nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node click the (+) and you will see more tables. For example: node__body

[image]

All you gotta do now is export this table as a CSV. Open the file on Microsof Excel. Then CTRL+F click on the replace tab, and replace filter_html with full_html. Save and import back to database, check mark replace data option. Then in Drupal clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks, it works. What I missed before is clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to No Sssweat. His answer works. But I prefer to use sql so here it is.

Using Phpmyadmin navigate to node__body table (or just search it) then in SQL tab, write this:

```
UPDATE `node__body` SET `body_format`='full_html' WHERE `body_format`='full_html1';
```

Please notice the following:

- in my case, I use different body format in my website so it is not good to change all body_format to full_html.
- after the migration I got full_html1, but you may get different body_format.

After execution the SQL command, Clear **Drupal cache**